# Работа со строками и ячейками DataTable

Tags: c#, excel

Есть `DataTable` и есть цикл

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;            
    int.TryParse(row["a"].ToString(), out a);
    int.TryParse(row["b"].ToString(),out b);

    row["a"] = sign + signfk;

}
```

`row["a"]` тип `int`

Соответственно получается, что столбец типа `int` и в нем хранятся целые значения.

Можно ли сделать так чтобы при `row["a"] = 0`, можно было конвертировать ячейку в string и задать значение для `row["a"] = "н/a"`.

Понимаю, что можно работать со списками и будет проще. Но так как происходит много действий с одной таблицей, нет смысла уже менять.

Отчет выводится из исходной таблицы в Excel.

Comment: Как не старайся, если столбец типа `int` записать в него `string` не получится.

Comment: может как-то можно удалить ячейку и заменить стринговой

Comment: @Михаил можно и так сделать

Comment: Пиши тогда NULL туда что ли

Comment: @May_be Как на моем примере заменить ячейку на стринг . Я с ячейками еще не сильно понимаю DataTable

Comment: @ЦовакСаакян null как-то не понятно смотрится в отчете для простых смертных.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, описав, как и куда происходит вывод данных. Добавьте теги.

Answer (score 1):

В `DataTable` нужно **хранить** то значение, которое и должно быть: 0.
А строку "н/a" нужно **показывать** при выводе данных пользователю.

Я не знаю, каким образом данные у вас представляются пользователю. Допустим, это делается с помощью `DataGridView`. Тогда можно назначить для определённой колонки нужную строку формата.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("a", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("b", typeof(int));

table.Rows.Add(1, 11);
table.Rows.Add(2, 22);
table.Rows.Add(0, 33);

var dataGridView = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
dataGridView.DataSource = table;

dataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0;-0;н/a";
```

Данные занесены в `DataTable` и привязаны к гриду. В последней строке кода для колонки с индексом 0 задан [формат](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Anchor_8) `"0;-0;н/a"` - положительные и отрицательные значения выводятся как есть, а вместо 0 - `н/а`.

Comment: Да это хороший ответ для datagridview. У меня вывод идет сразу в exel.

Comment: @Михаил - Полагаю, в Excel аналогично можно указать форматирование.